SonarQube API is giving me weird object IDs (like "AYvdIXCb14cadZhy_3ge")- how to match them up?
I'm making a call to api/measures/component?component=MyApplication&metricKeys=quality_gate_details - where the component is an application (i.e. a collection of projects).
I get back a list of projects in the application, and which projects are failing/passing their quality gates.  Which is great - it's exactly what I need.
Except that the ID for the project is not the normal ID - it's a bunch of semi-random keys.  How do I translate something like AYIBRZTmQ_aBcdefFQCX back into the correct project?
